# Get Average of Multiple Ranges from Multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a workbook that has an order form tab that generates orders as duplicates of the order form into new worksheets. I need to have the information from those worksheets averaged so I can find out the typical order.

This is what I've come up with so far just trying to add all the values together to display in the Trend Data worksheet:

```
Sub CalculateAvg()

        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        Dim I As Integer

        Dim wsTrend As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
        Set wsTrend = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trend Data")

        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         For I = 1 To WS_Count
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = "Order Form" Then Exit For 'exit loop if order form reached

            Set wsTemp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
            wsTrend.Range("D4:D53").Value = wsTrend.Range("D4:D53").Value + wsTemp.Range("F4:F53").Value

         Next I
End Sub
```

I get an Error 13 - Type Mismatch on the range1 = range1 + range2 line, which I don't quite understand.

I if I change that line to just
`wsTrend.Range("D4:D53").Value = wsTemp.Range("F4:F53").Value`

I don't get a type mismatch and it works.

I'm probably going about this in the wrong way or missing something simple, but I'm not sure what direction to take.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

edit, a bit of clarification:
Basically, I could have 100 worksheets that look like this but with different numbers:

```
apples 2
bananas 5
oranges 3
mangoes 10
```

I need to loop through all the worksheets and get the average for each item and display

```
avg apples 3
avg bananas 4
avg oranges 4
avg mangoes 8
```

Comment: You are using .Value against a variety of Ranges; Excel doesn't understand that you want to sum the values of all cells within those ranges together; you will need a function to actually do the summing, and you will then need to place that summed value somewhere - either a single cell, or as a stored variable.

Comment: Thank you Grade 'Eh' Bacon. Your response helped me think about how to work at it. Excel doesn't read minds, apparently. Hopefully that will be in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so Grade 'Eh' Bacon made me think about the problem differently.

This is what I've got:

```
Sub CalculateAvg()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim App_WS_Count As Integer
    App_WS_Count = 0

    Dim wsTrend As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet

    Set wsTrend = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trend Data")

    Dim TrendRange As Range
    Set TrendRange = wsTrend.Range("D4:D53")


    For A = 1 To TrendRange.Rows.Count
        TrendRange.Cells(A, 1).Clear
    Next A

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For I = 1 To WS_Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = "Order Form" Then Exit For 'exit loop if order form reached
        App_WS_Count = App_WS_Count + 1


        Set wsTemp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        Dim TempRange As Range
        Set TempRange = wsTemp.Range("F4:F53")     

        For C = 1 To TempRange.Rows.Count
            TrendRange.Cells(C, 1).Value = TrendRange.Cells(C, 1).Value + TempRange.Cells(C, 1).Value
        Next C

     Next I

     For A = 1 To TrendRange.Rows.Count
        TrendRange.Cells(A, 1).Value = TrendRange.Cells(A, 1).Value / App_WS_Count
     Next A
End Sub
```

This is probably really inefficient logically. And there are probably going to be annoying issues adding more rows for new items that get added to the order form down the road, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Could try modifying below

Works by reading the values into arrays and then an average is performed on the values in the array

```
Sub avg_test()
Dim Val1(), Val2(), Val3()

Val1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value
Val2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value
Val3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Value

avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Val1, Val2, Val3)

End Sub
```